# F# how to list functions with custom attribute?

Tags: f#, attributes

I'm trying to create some kind of interface, but i cannot find how to use custom attributes in F# as MSDN only shows usage of CLR attributes. This is what i want to achieve:

```
open System

type Command (name : string) =
    inherit Attribute()    
    member this.Name = name

[<Command("something")>]
let doSomething () = 
    Console.Write("I'm doing something") 

[<Command("somethingElse")>]
let doSomethingElse () =
    Console.Write("I'm doing something else") 

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    let command = Console.ReadLine()
    // find function where Command.Name = command and call it
    Console.Read()
    0
```

Comment: You need in to look into reflection: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Reflection and attributes should be a last resort, something you should only use if you really know what you're doing. Have you tried other approaches?

Comment: @MauricioScheffer thats untrue and irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extend on your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28392457/679898), a more generic approach would be to get all the types and then filter the functions that have the attribute you're looking for (as your approach would break down once your application grows and no longer has everything "packed" into the Program class):

```
let getCommands () =
    let types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
    let commands = 
        types 
        |> Array.collect (fun typ -> typ.GetMethods())
        |> Array.choose (fun mi -> 
            mi.CustomAttributes 
            |> Seq.tryFind (fun attr -> attr.AttributeType = typeof<Command>)
            |> Option.map (fun attr -> attr, mi))

    let commandsMap = 
        commands
        |> Seq.map (fun (attr, mi) -> 
            let name =
                let arg = attr.ConstructorArguments.[0]
                unbox<string> arg.Value
            name, mi)
        |> Map.ofSeq

    commandsMap
```

This gets all the functions from all the types in the executing assembly, then filters out everything that doesn't have command attribute. Then it builds a map where the key is the attribute argument and the value is the `MethodInfo` of the function.

Comment: I only looked for how to find that "unpacked" in classes functions, but for sure this is usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it.

```
Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("Program").GetMethods()
```

`Program` typename is not viable in code so it cannot be used in `typeof<Program>`, but this type exists and can be taken from assembly.

Comment: Not true, F# has a `typeof<'T>` operator.

Comment: But you cannot do `typeof<Program>` because this type is not viable in code.

Comment: I have eddited this answer to make it understandable.